# GTK+ Code Demos - compile Color Selector

Tags: gcc, gtk, gtk3

I found out that Color Selector from the GTK+ Code Demos is a quite nice color chooser. Thus, I would like to use it as a standalone application without having to run `gtk-demos` every time.

I tried to compile the example code which is:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static GtkWidget *window = NULL;
static GtkWidget *da;
static GdkColor color;
static GtkWidget *frame;

/* Expose callback for the drawing area
 */
static gboolean
expose_event_callback (GtkWidget      *widget, 
                       GdkEventExpose *event, 
                       gpointer        data)
{
  GdkWindow *window = gtk_widget_get_window (widget);

  if (window)
    {
      GtkStyle *style;
      cairo_t *cr;

      style = gtk_widget_get_style (widget);

      cr = gdk_cairo_create (window);

      gdk_cairo_set_source_color (cr, &style->bg[GTK_STATE_NORMAL]);
      gdk_cairo_rectangle (cr, &event->area);
      cairo_fill (cr);

      cairo_destroy (cr);
    }

  return TRUE;
}

static void
change_color_callback (GtkWidget *button,
               gpointer   data)
{
  GtkWidget *dialog;
  GtkColorSelection *colorsel;
  gint response;

  dialog = gtk_color_selection_dialog_new ("Changing color");

  gtk_window_set_transient_for (GTK_WINDOW (dialog), GTK_WINDOW (window));

  colorsel = 
    GTK_COLOR_SELECTION (gtk_color_selection_dialog_get_color_selection (GTK_COLOR_SELECTION_DIALOG (dialog)));

  gtk_color_selection_set_previous_color (colorsel, &color);
  gtk_color_selection_set_current_color (colorsel, &color);
  gtk_color_selection_set_has_palette (colorsel, TRUE);

  response = gtk_dialog_run (GTK_DIALOG (dialog));

  if (response == GTK_RESPONSE_OK)
    {
      gtk_color_selection_get_current_color (colorsel,
                         &color);

      gtk_widget_modify_bg (da, GTK_STATE_NORMAL, &color);
    }

  gtk_widget_destroy (dialog);
}

GtkWidget *
do_colorsel (GtkWidget *do_widget)
{
  GtkWidget *vbox;
  GtkWidget *button;
  GtkWidget *alignment;

  if (!window)
    {
      color.red = 0;
      color.blue = 65535;
      color.green = 0;

      window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
      gtk_window_set_screen (GTK_WINDOW (window),
                 gtk_widget_get_screen (do_widget));
      gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Color Selection");

      g_signal_connect (window, "destroy",
            G_CALLBACK (gtk_widget_destroyed), &window);

      gtk_container_set_border_width (GTK_CONTAINER (window), 8);

      vbox = gtk_vbox_new (FALSE, 8);
      gtk_container_set_border_width (GTK_CONTAINER (vbox), 8);
      gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), vbox);

      /*
       * Create the color swatch area
       */


      frame = gtk_frame_new (NULL);
      gtk_frame_set_shadow_type (GTK_FRAME (frame), GTK_SHADOW_IN);
      gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (vbox), frame, TRUE, TRUE, 0);

      da = gtk_drawing_area_new ();

      g_signal_connect (da, "expose_event",
            G_CALLBACK (expose_event_callback), NULL);

      /* set a minimum size */
      gtk_widget_set_size_request (da, 200, 200);
      /* set the color */
      gtk_widget_modify_bg (da, GTK_STATE_NORMAL, &color);

      gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (frame), da);

      alignment = gtk_alignment_new (1.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0);

      button = gtk_button_new_with_mnemonic ("_Change the above color");
      gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (alignment), button);

      gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (vbox), alignment, FALSE, FALSE, 0);

      g_signal_connect (button, "clicked",
            G_CALLBACK (change_color_callback), NULL);
    }

  if (!gtk_widget_get_visible (window))
    {
      gtk_widget_show_all (window);
    }
  else
    {
      gtk_widget_destroy (window);
      window = NULL;
    }

  return window;
}
```

The error is:

```
[orschiro@thinkpad ~]$ gcc `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0` -o colorSelector colorSelector.ccolorSelector.c: In function ‘expose_event_callback’:
colorSelector.c:26:7: warning: ‘gdk_cairo_set_source_color’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gdk/gdkcairo.h:58): Use 'gdk_cairo_set_source_rgba' instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
colorSelector.c: In function ‘change_color_callback’:
colorSelector.c:44:3: warning: ‘gtk_color_selection_dialog_new’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/deprecated/gtkcolorseldialog.h:73): Use 'gtk_color_chooser_dialog_new' instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
colorSelector.c:49:5: warning: ‘gtk_color_selection_dialog_get_color_selection’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/deprecated/gtkcolorseldialog.h:75): Use 'GtkColorChooser' instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
colorSelector.c:51:3: warning: ‘gtk_color_selection_set_previous_color’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/deprecated/gtkcolorsel.h:148) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
colorSelector.c:52:3: warning: ‘gtk_color_selection_set_current_color’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/deprecated/gtkcolorsel.h:142): Use 'gtk_color_chooser_set_rgba' instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
colorSelector.c:53:3: warning: ‘gtk_color_selection_set_has_palette’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/deprecated/gtkcolorsel.h:100) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
colorSelector.c:59:7: warning: ‘gtk_color_selection_get_current_color’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/deprecated/gtkcolorsel.h:145): Use 'gtk_color_chooser_get_rgba' instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
colorSelector.c: In function ‘do_colorsel’:
colorSelector.c:91:7: warning: ‘gtk_vbox_new’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/deprecated/gtkvbox.h:60): Use 'gtk_box_new' instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../lib/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Installed packages:

```
gtk2 2.24.14-1
gtk3 3.6.2-1
gcc-libs-multilib 4.7.2-2
gcc-multilib 4.7.2-2
```

Could someone please explain me the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your source code is incomplete, the `main` function is missing. gtk-demo is organised so it has a single `main` that calls some submodules and processes them the same way, and you're missing that `main`.

The other warning come from the fact that this example code you're trying to compile was done for GTK 2, and you're trying to build it against GTK 3.

You'll find all the missing parts in the [gtk-demo directory](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/tree/demos/gtk-demo) of the GTK+ repository.

Comment: Thank you. I guess it is not that simple to add the code of main.c before the code which I had posted above. Could you give me a tip what to do?

Comment: Could you please describe first your use case? I fail to see how useful that color selector could be when it's out of the context of a graphical application like GIMP or Inkscape. Is only the color selection dialog useful, or also the user interface with the color selection button and that big sample of the chosen color?

Comment: The use case is that I only need the color selector dialog to pick a color from anywhere on my screen. Thus, I do not need to open gtk-demo first just to get to the color-selector and therefore I want to have it as a standalone application. I hope this makes it clear. Regards